# EventListener without a Component

Tags: java, keylistener, event-listener, keylogger

Can I have a Java program that listens to the keyboard without having a Component?

Can I use the Interface KeyListener without having a visual component?

I don't need any of the functionality in java.awt. I don't need any windows/components or such. I just want the program to react to some input.

Comment: No, I am running some experiments on my computer, and want to be able to quit the experiment in the middle, by pressing Esc, which would cause a premature rounding up of the experiment, saving the intermediate results.

Comment: So put a 'stop' button on screen and attach an action listener.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: It's only nonsense when you know it is not that easily possible. A window with one button seems superfluous. Please refrain from calling anyone's serious remarks nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I have a Java program that listens to the keyboard without having a Component?

No.

> Can I use the Interface KeyListener without having a visual component?

No.

Comment: Re 2nd question asked for itself: [Why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65225649/1744774)

Answer (score 1):

Something has to be there that accepts the input so that the KeyListener is called.  You register a KeyListener with a component.  Having some kind of input component is required so you can register the KeyListener.

Remember, your code sits inside of the JVM.  The JVM is the one getting the direct signals from the underlying operating system -- not your code.

You could try creating a JNI hook into some native code.

Comment: So why can't the JVM give the signal to my program without a window? Why can't I register the KeyListener without a window?

Comment: It's possible, but afaik nothing currently exists.  You're better off creating a JNI hook into some native code.

Comment: *"better off creating a JNI hook into some native code"*  That should really be part of your answer.  I think it is the only way to achieve logging with no (owned - Java) components.

Answer (score 0):

Re „*Can I use the Interface KeyListener without having a visual component?*“

Yes, you can (if the question is asked for itself):

```java
package igb.so.SO19706590;

import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

class KeyEventProducerConsumerSample {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {

        final KeyEventProducerConsumerSample kes = new KeyEventProducerConsumerSample();
        final KeyEventProducer kep = kes.new KeyEventProducer();
        final KeyEventConsumer kec = kes.new KeyEventConsumer();

        kep.addKeyListener( kec ).raise();
    } // main()

    class KeyEventProducer {

        KeyListener kl;

        KeyEventProducer addKeyListener( final KeyListener kl ) {

            this.kl = kl;
            return this;
        } // addKeyListener()

        /** Creating KeyEvents programmatically, with no keyboard involved
         * and informing the KeyEventConsumer (KeyListener) about them.
         */
        void raise() {

            kl.keyTyped( new KeyEvent( new TextField(), 1, 1, 1, 1, '1' ) );
            kl.keyPressed( new KeyEvent( new TextField(), 2, 2, 2, 2, '2' ) );
            kl.keyReleased( new KeyEvent( new TextField(), 3, 3, 3, 3, '3' ) );
        } // raise()

    } // KeyEventProducer

    /** Using KeyListener interface without any visual component.
     */
    class KeyEventConsumer implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped( final KeyEvent ke ) {
            out.println( ke );
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed( final KeyEvent ke ) {
            out.println( ke );
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased( final KeyEvent ke ) {
            out.println( ke );
        }

    } // KeyEventConsumer

} // KeyEventProducerConsumerSample
```

#### Output

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[unknown type,keyCode=1,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x1,keyChar='1',modifiers=Shift,extModifiers=Shift,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on textfield0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[unknown type,keyCode=2,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x2,keyChar='2',modifiers=Ctrl,extModifiers=Ctrl,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on textfield1
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[unknown type,keyCode=3,keyText=Cancel,keyChar='3',modifiers=Ctrl+Shift,extModifiers=Ctrl+Shift,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on textfield2
```

Comment: You should clarify that even though it does use KeyListener, it in fact does not listen to your keyboard.